# Cannot include multiple webpack projects: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, php, npm, webpack

I have a small website where clients can track projects.
One part of the site is viewing a blueprint modelled with THREEjs and packaged with webpack.

I've been asked to add another type of blueprint to the site and have one working locally, however I cannot run both blueprints on the site at the same time. Either of them work individually but if I import both at once (php include 'print1.js'; include 'print2.js';?) I get the error: *Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list.*

package.json looks like so:

```
{
  "name": "print2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "appl.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "dat.gui": "^0.7.6",
    "three": "^0.112.1",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "node_modules/webpack/"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

and my webpack.config.js like so:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/print2.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'print2.js',
    publicPath: './dist/'
  },
  mode: 'production',
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader" }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

The earlier blueprint has some of the same dependencies with different (older) versions.

I'm not exporting anything from my js-files but loading everything with `window.onload = function(){` at the moment.

What can I do to run both blueprints simultaneously?

*PS. I'm not missing a closing parenthesis in my code. Both projects run fine on their own. DS.*

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was me being a newbie..

It had nothing to do with webpack (apart from possibly the .map file giving me weird error messages)

The real issue was that both the threejs files were making use of

```
window.onload = function() {
```

By instead making use of jQuery and

```
$(window).load(function(){
```

in my file the application now runs as it should.